# Manejo de Transacciones en Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estoy trabajando con Entity Framework 6 enfoque code-first, ¿Es necesario usar transaction cuando se registra cabecera y detalle, cuando se usa EF6?

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(Compra entity)
    {
        using (var context = new PosContext())
        {
            //CABECERA
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;

            //DETALLE
            foreach (var d in entity.DetalleCompras)
            {
                context.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Es necesario usar transaction cuando se registra cabecera y detalle, cuando se usa EF6?

En tu caso en particular, no lo necesitas.

Primero, hay que tomar en cuenta que las sentencias siguientes aún no mandan los cambios a la base de datos. Mas bien, acumulan los cambios en memoria hasta que luego ejecutes `SaveChanges()`.  De modo que hasta aquí, aún no hay necesidad de una transacción.

```
//CABECERA
context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;

//DETALLE
foreach (var d in entity.DetalleCompras)
{
    context.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Added;
}
```

Ahora bien, cuando ejecutas:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

...ahora sí, EF manda todos los cambios acumulados a la base de datos, incluyendo cabecera y detalle. Pero aquí tampoco necesitas preocuparte de manejar una transacción manualmente, porque EF automáticamente se encarga de ejecutar `SaveChanges()` dentro de una transacción.

Esto lo deja bien claro la [documentación para EF6+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx):

> In all versions of Entity Framework, whenever you execute `SaveChanges()` to insert, update or delete on the database the framework will wrap that operation in a transaction. This transaction lasts only long enough to execute the operation and then completes. When you execute another such operation a new transaction is started.

Traducido:

> En todas las versiones de Entity Framework, cuando ejecutas `SaveChanges()` para agregar, modificar o borrar registros en la base de datos, EF envuelve (o rodea) la operación en un transacción. Esta transacción dura solo lo suficiente para que se ejecute la operación, y luego se termina. Cuando ejecutas otra operación de este tipo, se comienza una transacción distinta.

Answer (score 1):

Depende mi estimado, `Entity Framework` utiliza `transaction` de manera interna cuando ejecutas un `SaveChanges()`

Si vas a realizar algo complejo, te sugiero revisar `TransactionScope`

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Data.Entity; 
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Transactions; 

namespace TransactionsExamples 
{ 
    class TransactionsExample 
    { 
        static void StartOwnTransactionWithinContext() 
        { 
            using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
            { 
                using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
                { 
                    try 
                    { 
                        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( 
                            @"UPDATE Blogs SET Rating = 5" + 
                                " WHERE Name LIKE '%Entity Framework%'" 
                            ); 

                        var query = context.Posts.Where(p => p.Blog.Rating >= 5); 
                        foreach (var post in query) 
                        { 
                            post.Title += "[Cool Blog]"; 
                        } 

                        context.SaveChanges(); 

                        dbContextTransaction.Commit(); 
                    } 
                    catch (Exception) 
                    { 
                        dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Referencia: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx

Comment: Hola, si es como dice el enunciado de la pregunta, ¿es necesario usar manejo de transacciones para registrar cabecera y detalle? si EF lo hace de manera interna entonces esta por demás manejar transacciones, el ejemplo que muestras no es Transaction Scope.

Comment: Si muestras el código que has hecho, podríamos definir si es necesario o no. Por eso te dije "Depende". El ejemplo mostrado es de transacciones

Comment: Ya inclui el código.